# How to construct this solr parameters with uri.typolink

Tags: solr, typo3, template-engine, fluid, typolink

How does it work if I want to construct the following structure with Typo3's Fluid uri.typolink viewhelper:

```
/de/suche/?tx_solr[q]=&tx_solr[filter][0]=result_type_filter:award
```

This is the viewhelper and data should go inside additionaParams, if I'm not wrong.
`{f:uri.typolink(parameter: 2881, addQueryString: 1, additionalParams: 'structureGoesHere')}`

example:

```
{f:uri.typolink(parameter: 2881, addQueryString: 1, additionalParams: 'example')}
```

output:

```
/de/suche/?tx_solr%5Bq%5D=&example=
```

decoded:

```
/de/suche/?tx_solr[q]=&example=
```

I'm stuck the hard way... just using typo3 for the first time trying to wrap my head around everything, any help is much appreciated.

further explanation: (typo3, fluid, solr)
you might ask yourself why do I need this specific structure... we reworked our solr facet architecture - first we used "top nav" buttons where we filtered results per page config - now we replaced this approach with facets for the counter of the specific facets in the top nav - so now we have to pass the correct facet as a parameter to know which results to display on reload (ajaxify does not work in this situation, its just for the side menu). This is were the uri.typolink approach finds use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you really need a typolink viewhelper, or could you also use the uri.page viewhelper?

**uri.page viewhelper:**

```
<f:uri.page pageUid="2881" additionalParams="{tx_solr: {q: '', filter: {0: 'result_type_filter:award'}}}" />
```

**Or inline notation:**

```
{f:uri.page(pageUid:'2881', additionalParams: '{tx_solr: {q: \'\', filter: {0: \'result_type_filter:award\'}}}')}
```

You have to nest an array to achieve tx_solr[filter][0] by:

```
filter: {0: 'result_type_filter:award'}
```